# how to create a parametrized access query and initialize it with variable in excel vba

Tags: ms-access, excel, vba

can you help me on how to create a dynamic access query ( parametrized access query )&

initialize it with a variable  in excel vba

eX: Select & from customers where id = 1

where id = 1 should be initialized with a variable like where id = @id

Answer (score 3):

Here is a parameter query I created and tested in Access.

```
PARAMETERS [@id] Long;
SELECT c.id, c.customer_name
FROM customers AS c
WHERE (((c.id)=[@id]));
```

I can use ADO in Excel to assign a value for the parameter and retrieve a recordset based on that query.  Here is the code for the new module I created in Excel.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub AdoCommandWithParameter()
    Const cstrDbPath As String = "C:\share\Access\whiteboard2003.mdb"
    'Dim cmd As ADODB.Command '
    'Dim cn As ADODB.Connection '
    'Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset '
    Dim cmd As Object
    Dim cn As Object
    Dim rs As Object
    Dim strConnString As String
    Dim strSql As String

    strSql = "PARAMETERS [@id] Long;" & vbCrLf & _
        "SELECT c.id, c.customer_name" & vbCrLf & _
        "FROM customers AS c" & vbCrLf & _
        "WHERE (((c.id)=[@id]));"
    Debug.Print strSql

    strConnString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & vbCrLf & _
        "Data Source=" & cstrDbPath & ";" & vbCrLf & _
        "Mode=Share Deny None;"

    'Set cn = New ADODB.Connection '
    Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    cn.CursorLocation = 3 ' adUseClient '
    cn.Open strConnString

    'Set cmd = New ADODB.Command '
    Set cmd = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
    cmd.CommandText = strSql
    cmd.ActiveConnection = cn
    cmd.Parameters("[@id]") = 1
    Set rs = cmd.Execute

    Debug.Print "RecordCount: " & rs.RecordCount

    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    Set cmd = Nothing
    cn.Close
    Set cn = Nothing
End Sub
```

Change the value for *cstrDbPath* to match the location and name of your Access db file.

The trickiest part is getting the connection string right. If you have trouble, see [ConnectionStrings.com](http://connectionstrings.com/).

I wrote that procedure to use late binding for ADO.  If you want early binding instead, you will need to set a reference for an available version of the *Microsoft ActiveX Data Object Library*.  And switch to the lines I commented out.

This is the line where you set the parameter's value:

```
cmd.Parameters("[@id]") = 1
```

Change it to supply the value you want; we don't know where that value is coming from.

You will probably want to do something with the recordset other than to `Debug.Print` its `RecordCount`, but we have no clue what that might be.  :-)